# How to set the rectangular box outside the chart using mpchart library in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to plot a graph using MPchart library in android.
But I am not able to show a rectangular box outside the chart with background color as green as shown in the picture:[image: expected output of graph 1].

I tried using these  methods of MPchart library:

1. `setDrawGridBackground(true);`
2. `setGridBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);`

Instead of setting the color outside chart it is setting the background color of the chart as shown in the picture below: [image: output obtained using the above methods of MPchart in android in graph 2].

```
chart.setDrawGridBackground(true);
chart.setGridBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Please provide any suggestions so that I can get my graph output as expected in picture 1

Comment: this is the mpchart library used "com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2 "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used mpchart library 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'

```
//for refrence I used static values
 // X co-ordinate 

   ArrayList sales=new ArrayList();

    sales.add(new BarEntry(900f,0));
    sales.add(new BarEntry(1150f,1));
    sales.add(new BarEntry(780f,2));
    sales.add(new BarEntry(1050f,3));
    sales.add(new BarEntry(1180f,4));
    sales.add(new BarEntry(1200f,5));
    sales.add(new BarEntry(1160f,6));
    sales.add(new BarEntry(1220f,7));
    sales.add(new BarEntry(1100f,8)); 

 // Y co-ordinate 
ArrayList<String> month=new ArrayList<>();

    month.add("June");
    month.add("July");
    month.add("Aug.");
    month.add("Sept.");
    month.add("Oct.");
    month.add("Nov.");
    month.add("Dec.");


 BarDataSet barDataSet=new BarDataSet(sales,"Total Sales");
   //animate
    barChart.animateY(2000);
   //set colors 
    barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    BarData barData=new BarData(month,barDataSet);
    barChart.setData(barData);

   //xml in layout
   <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/bar_chart">

</com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart>
```

Hope this answer will help you.
**Output :**
[image: Output look like :]

Comment: how to show label that describes the x-Axis as months outside the chart

Comment: Check out above answer (just edited) to set month to Y-axis (as shown in fig.).I didn't try to set month X-Axis , let me check. @priya

Comment: how to add scale label in mpchart @mohsin

Comment: According to PhilJay (owner of library) String (Scale?) label are not supported currently by default. You have add Text View outside the chart.Look Answer given by PhilJay on github  https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/234#issuecomment-64538937       @priya

Answer (score 2):

In xml file add background attribute to barchart element.

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
android:id="@+id/bar_chart"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00AAA7"/>
```

use below method of mpchart library:

```
setDrawGridBackground(true);
```

output looks like in the image link
[Barchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmnLQ.png)